# What does `(c = *str) != 0` mean?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, syntax

```
int equiv (char, char);
int nmatches(char *str, char comp) {
    char c;
    int n=0;
    while ((c = *str) != 0) {  
       if (equiv(c,comp) != 0) n++;
      str++;
    }
    return (n);    
}
```

What does "(c = *str) != 0" actually mean?
Can someone please explain it to me or help give me the correct terms to search for an explanation myself?

Comment: This dereferences the pointer `str` and assigns the value it points to to `c` and then compares `c` to zero.

Comment: `*str` takes value from address of `str`; `c = *str` assigns this value to `c`; `(c = *str) != 0` checks if this value is not `NULL`. `NULL` is the end of string marker in C/C++, see "null terminated string" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

Comment: Also you probably don't know that assignment has a value. For example one can write (a=(b=c)) == d in C/C++. Here each assignment is not just assigns value from right to left, but also returns it outside of the parentheses.

Comment: If the pointer passed is not pointing at a nul terminated string, bad ... bad ... undefined things start to happen, if you're using C++ you should be using `std::string`.

Comment: @Dims `NULL` is used the depict null-pointer, not nul termination. Mixing those causes confusion. Also, no answers in comments, please.

Comment: @user694733 see my Wiki link

Comment: @Dims it's a null-terminated string not a NULL-terminated string - the character is a NUL not a NULL. I've made this mistake myself in the recent past too :/

Comment: @ChrisTurner okay, strictly speaking you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression has two parts:

- `c = *str` - this is a simple assignment of `c` from dereferencing a pointer,
- `val != 0` - this is a comparison to zero.

This works, because assignment is an *expression*, i.e. it has a value. The value of the assignment is the same as the value being assigned, in this case, the `char` pointed to by the pointer. So basically, you have a loop that traces a null-terminated string to the end, assigning each individual `char` to `c` as it goes.

Note that the `!= 0` part is redundant in C, because the control expression of a `while` loop is implicitly compared to zero:

```
while ((c = *str)) {
    ...
}
```

The second pair of parentheses is optional from the syntax perspective, but it's kept in assignments like that in order to indicate that the assignment is intentional. In other words, it tells the readers of your code that you really meant to write an assignment `c = *str`, and not a comparison `c == *str`, which is a lot more common inside loop control blocks. The second pair of parentheses also suppresses the compiler warning.

Comment: `!= 0` is redundant,  Yet so is this answer's alternative of the extra `()`  redundant.  Both serve the same purpose: to quiet compiler warnings and provide clarity that code is not `c == *str`.  Depending on _style_ and experience, one is more preferred than the other.

Answer (score 2):

Confusingly,

`while ((c = *str) != 0) {`

is a tautology of the considerably easier to read

`while (c = *str) {`

This also has the effect of assigning the character at `*str` to `c`, and the loop will terminate once `*str` is `\0`; i.e. when the end of the string has been reached.

Assignments within conditionals such as the above can be confusing on first glance, (cf. the behaviour of the very different `c == *str`), but they are such a useful part of C and C++, you need to get used to them.

Comment: I think that you man that one is equivalent to the other (i.e. their equivalence is a tautology).

Comment: I am not sure whether to call the assignment a "side" effect.

Comment: Prefer `while ((c = *str))` in order to suppress any potential warnings about a mistaken `==`.

Comment: @Bathsheba: without the parentheses, clang gives a warning "using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses". In order to suppress it, you must either put the additional parens or pass `-Wno-parentheses`, of which I choose the former.

Comment: @Bathsheba: But complexity is not a virtue. ([Funny opening by Herb Sutter](https://youtu.be/xnqTKD8uD64).) I prefer the first variant, I would even write `while ((c = *str) != '\0')` to make it clear that I am looking for the null terminator. The line `while (c = *str)` is correct, but I will wonder whether you really meant `==` there. The added parentheses work like a “sic” and that is a good thing. Writing `strcpy(char *d, char *s) { while (*d++ = *s++); }` might be cool, but I wouldn't want to have that in my code.

Comment: @MartinUeding: Perhaps I'm old fashioned - and appeal to authority does nothing for me - and yes I would emit `while (*d++ = *s++);` into my codebase since it tells you exactly what is going on and is extremely descriptive (just make sure `d` is not `s` else the behaviour is UB). All the folk in my team are expected to know C and C++ in depth. But you do raise important points.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I agree that knowing the language in depth is a good thing. But that short `strcpy` has many things where it could go wrong. One example would be `*++d = *++s`. Or if the operators were binding like `(*d)++ = (*s)++`. So I would write it out in a few more lines. I tried to do a [little benchmark](https://gist.github.com/martin-ueding/a62e9d0348a15544635a9fe29d59db73). The ultra short version seems to be a tad slower on occasion, but that might not be statistically significant. I do see, however, that the longer version is not slower, therefore I'd take that one.

Answer (score 1):

`(c = *str)` is an *expression* and that has a value in itself. It is an *assignment*, the value of an assignment is the assigned value. So the value of `(c = *str)` is the value of `*str`.

The code basically checks, whether the value of `*str`, which just has been assigned to `c` is not `0`. In case it isn't, then it will call the function `equiv` with that value.

Once the `0` is assigned, this is the end of the string. The function has to stop reading from the memory, which it does.

Answer (score 1):

It's looping over every character in the string `str`, assigning them to `c` and then seeing if `c` is equal to 0 which would indicate the end of the string.

Although really the code should use `'\0'` as that is more obviously a NUL character.

Answer (score 0):

We are going through the str in the while loop and extract every char symbol in it until it is equal to zero - the main rule of the end of char string.

Here is 'for' loop equivalent:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i )
       std::cout << str[i];
```

Comment: "*... until it is not equal to zero ...*" should read "*... until it is equal to zero ...*" shouldn't it?

Comment: Right. Consequences of a literal translation from my language :)

Comment: Putting strlen as the conditional check runs the risk of this becoming O(N * N). A compiler might optimise out but I wouldn't depend on that.

Answer (score 0):

It is just sloppily written code. The intention is to copy a character from the string `str` into `c` and then check if it was the null terminator.

The idiomatic way to check for the null terminator in C is an explicit check against `'\0'`:

```
if(c != '\0')
```

This is so-called self-documenting code, since the de facto standard way to write the null terminator in C is by using the octal escape sequence `\0`.

---

Another mistake is to use assignment inside conditions. This was recognized as bad practice back in the 1980s and since then every compiler gives a warning against such code, "possibly incorrect assignment" or similar. This is bad practice because assignment includes a side effect and expressions with side effects should be kept as simple as possible. But it is also bad practice because it is easy to mix up `=` and `==`.

---

The code could easily be rewritten as something more readable and safe:

```
c = *str;
while (c != '\0')
{
  if(equiv(c, comp) != 0)
  {
    n++;
  }
  str++;
  c = *str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `char c` since you already have the pointer `char *str`, also you can replace `!= 0` with `!= '\0'` for better readability (if not compatibility)

```
while (*str != '\0')
{  
    if (equiv((*str),comp)
          != 0)
    { n++; }

    str++;   
}
```

To understand what the code does, you can read it like this

```
while ( <str> pointed-to value is-not <end_of_string> )
{
    if (function <equiv> with parameters( <str> pointed-to value, <comp> )
            returned non-zero integer value)
    then { increment <n> by 1 }

    increment pointer <str> by 1 x sizeof(char) so it points to next adjacent char
}
```